# Missing Login screen (kdm missing? plasma5)

Tags: kubuntu, login, lightdm, plasma

I installed plasma5 on 14.10 and had bunch of problems. I was in a hurry to fix, so removed/reinstalled blah blah blah bunch of packages, including probably lightdm and kdm.

Now I want Plasma5 back, so installed that, but I think i'm missing whatever that manages the login. What should I install? I guess I can install `kdm`or `lightdm`, but not sure which, or if there's something else plasma5 uses...

Comment: @florian-diesch @eric-carvalho @charles-green @mniess @psusi.. what makes you think this is a bug? If you just read the question you would have seen I was asking whether to install `kdm` or `lightdm`....!!!

Answer (score 1):

Installed lightdm, and works fine.